# send email after filling a form

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, email

I'm trying to create in a website in codeigniter a functionality to always that someone fill a Form it will create an entry in my database and send an email with that information.

Now I already have everything so it goes to the database but i need to know how to sent the email.

```
<div class="col-md-7 contact-form">
            <form method="post" action="contact" >
                <input placeholder="Assunto" type="text" value="{$nome}" name="nome" >
                <input placeholder="Email" type="text" value="{$email}" name="email" >
                <textarea placeholder="Message" type="text" value="{$content}" name="content"></textarea>
                <input type="submit" value="SEND">
            </form>
        </div>
```

Thank You!

Comment: The email needs to be sent by the back-end code. Who are you hosting with? They may have a demo script for this in their docs / knowledge base.

Comment: Yes, I know but I don't know if it's something in the controller or in the model. The aswers said it is in the controller so I know now, I'm a rookie in codeigniter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CodeIgniter built-in email library

> [Email Class](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/email.html)

In your case, i think its better to give "name" attribute to the submit button:

```
<input type='submit' name='somesubmitbutton' value='SEND' />
```

And then using it to verify before sending email:

```
if(!is_null($this->input->post("somesubmitbutton"))){
 $email  = $this->input->post("email");
 $name   = $this->input->post("name");
 $config = [
          'mailtype'  => 'html',
          'charset'   => 'utf-8',
          'protocol'  => 'smtp',
          'smtp_host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
          'smtp_user' => 'email@gmail.com', // You must turn ON "Allow less secure apps" in this gmail account (open https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps)
          'smtp_pass'   => 'emailpassword',
          'smtp_crypto' => 'ssl',
          'smtp_port'   => 465,
          'crlf'    => "\r\n",
          'newline' => "\r\n"
            ];

 $this->load->library('email',$config);
 $this->email->from('email@gmail.com', 'Sender Name');

 // EMAIL TO
 $this->email->to($email);

 $this->email->subject("Hello!");
 $this->email->message("Good afternoon $name!");
 $this->email->send();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use phpmailer library for sending emails

> library source : https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

```
<?php

require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();                            // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';              // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                     // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'example@gmail.com'; // your email id
$mail->Password = 'password'; // your password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                  
$mail->Port = 587;     //587 is used for Outgoing Mail (SMTP) Server.
$mail->setFrom('sendfrom@gmail.com', 'Name');
$mail->addAddress('sendto@yahoo.com');   // Add a recipient
$mail->isHTML(true);  // Set email format to HTML

$bodyContent = '<h1>HeY!,</h1>';
$bodyContent .= '<p>This is a email that Radhika send you From LocalHost using PHPMailer</p>';
$mail->Subject = 'Email from Localhost by Radhika';
$mail->Body    = $bodyContent;
if(!$mail->send()) {
  echo 'Message was not sent.';
  echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo 'Message has been sent.';
}

?>
```

Comment: What makes you assume OP has `PHPMailerAutoload.php`?